# How do I grab text from a text file within a boundary of line numbers pythonically?

Tags: file, parsing, text, python

I am trying to fetch data from the text file. The lines of interest in the text file are those that match 'Marker 2' all the way till the last instance of 'Marker 3'. There can be multiple Markers (duplicates). I wanted the min line number of the 'Marker 2' and max line number of 'Marker 3' - all the text within that min/max. While this works, I want to see how to do this the pythonic way, more efficient and lesser code.

Why did I have to open the same file twice? It was giving me otherwise, xreadlines and readlines conflicting?

**file_seeklines.py**

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

line_number = []
number = 0

## Fetch the boundary(start, end points)
f = open(filename,'r')

for line in f.xreadlines():
    number += 1
    if "marker 2" in line.strip().lower():
        line_number.append(number)
    if "marker 3" in line.strip().lower():    
        line_number.append(number)

#print line_number[0], line_number[-1]
start, end = line_number[0]-1, line_number[-1]

f.close()

## Grab the boundary 
g = open(filename,'r')

linelist = g.readlines()

try:
    for i in xrange(start, end):
        print linelist[i]
except:
    print "failed"
    pass
g.close()
```

**file.txt**

```
Welcome notice
------------------------
Hello there, welcome! Foo
Marker 0
hello

world

Bar
Yes!
Foo

How are ya?!

Bar

Have a great day!

Marker 1

Hello 1 2
12

MarKer 2
Hello 23
23
Marker 3
Hello 34
34

marker 2
Hello 45
45
MArker 3
```

**output**

```
MarKer 2

Hello 23

23

Marker 3

Hello 34

34



marker 2

Hello 45

45

MArker 3
```

Comment: By the way, the code as written reads from the min line containing `marker 2` *or* `marker 3` to the max line containing `marker 2` *or* `marker 3`.

Comment: While it does min or max, I then fetch the boundary of min/max from the list. I want to do a greedy grab of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file's not to large to `read()` into memory, you could go for a regex approach (taking advantage of the fact that the `*` operator is greedy):

```
import re
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    inBetween = re.search(r"Marker 2(.*)Marker 3", f.read(), re.S | re.I).group()
```

Another option is to iterate through the lines in both directions, stopping at the first occurence of "Marker 2" and Marker 3", respectively:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if "marker 2" in lines[i].lower():
            start = i
            break
    else:
        start = None

    for i in range(len(lines), -1, -1):
        if "marker 3" in lines[i].lower():
            end = i
            break
    else:
        end = None

    if None not in (start, end):
        inBetween = lines[start + 1:end]
    else:
        #one of the markers is missing, handle here.
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' - it is not matching the pattern

Comment: @ThinkCode: Add the flag `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: Tried with IGNORECASE, no dice. Your other solution is giving TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len() error.

Comment: @ThinkCode: Hmmm your right. Ah, check out Acorn's answer. try adding the re.DOTALL and re.IGNORECASE flags.

Comment: @ThinkCode: No problem. Thanks for reminding me to test my answers before posting them :P

Comment: How do I modify the regex to fetch only the first set of matches? Say : Marker 2.... Marker 3 instead of Marker 2...Marker 3...Marker 2....Marker 3...? I want it to return the first group since the full min max search fro some files is so many lines at times. Thanks!

Comment: This makes it non-greedy (.*?) if anyone is looking for a solution to my question : inBetween = re.search(r"Marker 2(.*?)Marker 3", f.read(), re.S | re.I).group()

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you're not just using a regular expression? i.e. `(marker 2.*marker 3)` with `re.DOTALL` and `re.IGNORECASE` flags.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `readlines()` but `read()` so that you won't have to iterate over lines.

You could then find the part you're interested in with `split()`.

E.g.

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    text = f.read().lower().split("marker 2",1)[1]
    text = text.rsplit("marker 3",1)[0]

    print('marker 2\n'+text+'marker 3')
```

Comment: Only the last match is being grabbed. Not returning the boundary.

Comment: It now gives me the entire text file.

Comment: I'm thinking it over. But the question asks for only one match, right?

Comment: It should be `f.read().split("marker 2", 1)[1].rsplit("marker 3", 1)[0]`

Comment: No, the boundary - (min, max). Min is first occurence of 'Marker 2' and Max is max occurence of 'Marker 3'.

Comment: Ok so you can do it with split, but you have to ignore the case (e.g. by lowercasing the text first). I tried to avoid regex but it might be better/necessary in this case.